# Ist es möglich allen Präpositionen wo- und da- voranzustellen?

Tags: preposition, word-formation

Ist es möglich allen Präpositionen wo- und da- voranzustellen?

Zum Beispiel: womit/damit, wofür/dafür ... und so weiter?

Wenn nicht, gibt es einige logische Regeln welche sind akzeptabel und welche nicht?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht? Meinst du ob es für jede Präposition ein da-wort/wo-wort gibt? Wenn ja, dann ist dein Satz falsch. Das direkte Objekt von "voranstellen" (hier die Präpositionen) ist das, was irgendwo vorangestellt wird. Es ist nicht der "Rezipient". Alternative: Ist es möglich allen Präpositionen (Dativ) wo- und da- (direkte Objekte, Akkusativ) voranzustellen.

Comment: @Emanuel Danke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um deine Frage zu beantworten: Strikte Regeln sind mir nicht bekannt, auch wenn es mit den meisten Dativ- und Akkusativ-Präpositionen funktioniert. Beginnt die Präposition mit einem Konsonanten, so  werden die Vorsilben wo- und da- benutzt. Beginnt sie dagegen mit einem Vokal, wird wor- und dar- verwendet. Es gibt jedoch einige Ausnahmen und die so entstandenen Wörter haben oft noch weitere, nicht offensichtliche Bedeutungen. Deshalb halte ich es für sinnvoller, diese Wörter wie normale Vokabeln zu lernen und nicht von einer Regel abzuleiten.

Beginn mit Konsonant:

für ➔ wofür, dafür
mit ➔ womit, damit
vor ➔ wovor, davor
hinter ➔ wohinter, dahinter
gegen ➔ wogegen, dagegen
zwischen ➔ "wozwischen" (richtig, aber selten), dazwischen

Beginn mit Vokal:

in ➔ wo**r**in, da**r**in
auf ➔ wo**r**auf, da**r**auf
unter ➔ wo**r**unter, da**r**unter
über ➔ wo**r**über, da**r**über
an ➔ wo**r**an, da**r**an
um ➔ worum, darum (Achtung! Mehrere Bedeutungen)

**Beispiele für Ausnahmen:**

neben ➔ daneben, "woneben" existiert zwar laut Duden, wird aber kaum verwendet und wirkt seltsam; besser ist als Frage "neben wem/was?" bzw. im Relativsatz "neben dem/der/dem …"
trotz ➔ trotz wem/was?, trotzdem
wegen ➔ **wes**wegen, **des**wegen
ohne ➔ nicht möglich; es muss "ohne wen/was?" bzw. "ohne den/die/das …" benutzt werden.
außer ➔ nicht möglich; es muss "außer wem/was?" bzw. "außer dem/der/dem …" benutzt werden.

Comment: "ohne" is missing